# The USB Port is loose. Device automatically disconnects. Manually have to replug it to make it work

Tags: usb

I have a loose USB port on my PC. I have a nice and working Oraimo USB that I brought it from the market. I use the USB for running my applications on my device. So I have this problem that the USB port is loose and whenever I pick my device, the device disconnects. I have no option but to manually replug it again and again. The USB is working on other computers and on the rear ports also.

What is the solution for it? I have cleaned the dust of the port but no fix. I do not want to just keep replugging it manually again and again. I have only one USB for charging and debugging. I can apply the USB to the rear port but when I have to switch off my computer so how can I charge my device?

My PC is a LENOVO 7558K4Q with Windows 11 that I have been using for ten years.

Comment: So just kidding, here too?

Comment: Use rear connectors or repair!  Or scrap 10 year old computer!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is just one remedy; physical R.E.P.A.I.R.

Possible ONLY If our device is built in a manner that allows that.
*(Many devices are HARD to repair! Generally; the smaller, the harder)*

... and YES: It requires relevant knowledge, skill and tools.

Comment: Why? Isn't there any other option?  I can't afford to buy a new PC.

Comment: What other options are you thinking of exactly?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe open up the computer and fix it?

Comment: Yes, and that is **exactly** what the answer above says.

Comment: I am planning to do so. But I don't have knoweledge about the inside of a pc. I can tamper with anything and pc is finsih

Comment: If you don't feel competent to repair it and can't afford to replace it, your remaining options are to find someone who is competent (and maybe pay them?) or live with the problem.

Comment: Get a  cheap hub with a long lead.

Comment: @user10489 My friend is a computer guy. He knows everything about Computers. I will try to reach him.  He is saying that he will come in 5 days cause he's out of town

Comment: Likely you need an electronics guy with some soldering skills, rather than a computer guy.  But maybe you get lucky and it is only a mechanical problem.